# Run Android Studio in 2gb Ram without Emulator

Tags: android

Is it possible to run android studio with SDK on  2Gb RAM AND 32 BIT INTEL ATOM PROCESSOR?

I wanna use my Android phone instead of AVD and only want to use the IDE.

Comment: yaa its possible.. i also used..

Answer (score 2):

am using Android Studio 2.2.3 with Lenovo S10, Intel Atom, 2GB Ram.  It works, but newer Android Studio upgrades does not start anymore..

Answer (score 1):

You can find standard system requirements by google here [Download Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#Requirements)

The listed specs say :

1. 64-bit distribution capable of running 32-bit applications
2. 3 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended; plus 1 GB for the Android Emulator
3. 2 GB of available disk space minimum, 4 GB Recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android SDK and emulator system image)
4. 1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution

I have checked my RAM usage, 8GB RAM (current computer) is enough for Android studio.

if you gonna use Emulator, you will need atleast 8GB ram computer.

I was facing performance issues for Android studio on computer 4GB ram(with emulator).

Answer (score 0):

**System Requirements For Android Studio**

**Check Here:** https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#Requirements

1. OS version Microsoft Windows 10/8/7 (32- or 64-bit)
2. RAM 2 or 3 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended
3. Disk space 500 MB disk space for Android Studio, at least 1.5 GB for Android SDK, emulator system images, and caches
4. Java version Java Development Kit (JDK) 8

NOTE: You Can Used Your Phone For App Check. So Need of Emulator.

> In Performance Wise Its May be hang your System or You Face the Speed Issue But Its Work Fine.